# How to update table row and add + 1 in row field every 1 minutes

Tags: php, sql

i have a table with users name and this table have a points row i want update table points row and add + 1 in row field every 1 minutes
this is my table

```
`id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `user` text,
  `points` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
```

Comment: I'm sure there is a way other than Cron Job

Comment: There is. The cronjob solution is pretty horrible

Answer (score 2):

You don't want to do this.  Instead, store the date/time when something is put into the table and then count the number of minutes when you fetch records.  This could be to the current time or to a close time.

Doing an update on the table is highly non-scalable.  If you had thousands of users, you would be putting a load of thousands of updates a minute on your system.  That just increases hardware requirements, increases query load, increases latency, and is a bad design.